# nextJS / NodeJS keeps triggering ip_ban

Tags: node.js, next.js, plesk

So not sure why, but my nodeJS / NextJS app keeps triggering plesks ip_ban. I recoded our site and moved it away from ReactJS to NextJS. But seems by doing so their must be a command that is making it look like an IP address is trying to connect to many times which makes the plesk server add the IP to a ban list (the rule that keeps getting triggered is - recidive).

I am wondering what is the correct way to solve this issue. Disabling ip_ban is a temp solution but not the ideal solution.

my server.js script is very clear and has no issues (once ip_ban is disabled).

```
const { createServer } = require("http");
const { parse } = require("url");
const next = require("next");
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";

const port = !dev ? process.env.PORT : 3000;

// Create the Express-Next App
const app = next({ dev });
const handle = app.getRequestHandler();

app
  .prepare()
  .then(() => {
    createServer((req, res) => {
      const parsedUrl = parse(req.url, true);
      const { pathname, query } = parsedUrl;
      handle(req, res, parsedUrl);
      console.log("pathname", pathname);
    }).listen(port, (err) => {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log(`> Ready on http://example.com:${port}`);
    });
  })
  .catch((ex) => {
    console.error(ex.stack);
    process.exit(1);
  });
```

The rule that keeps getting triggered:

```
[recidive]
enabled = true
filter = recidive
action = iptables-allports[name=recidive]
logpath = /var/log/fail2ban.log
maxretry = 3
```

Comment: Your page getting automaticaly refreshed when visiting urls with params ? any solution u found for this? what path u set for document root ?

Comment: Ended up disabling the firewall rule